# Nodejs pm2 with ubuntu not works after update

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have been running a nodejs server application that worked fine with **pm2** but after updating my virtual box **Ubuntu** to **18.04.2 LTS**. `pm2 list` shows that the server is online, but it is inaccessible when I go to the corresponding URL.

I tried to `kill pm2`, `reinstall pm2` many times and `reboot ubuntu`, but still it is not working.

PM2 show that application online, so I have no errors to show. I made no changes on my nodejs application.

I can ping from outside to my virtual box.

If I initialize with `pm2 start index.js` or `pm2 start --only serverName --env development` works but this method is configured with localhost.

When I use `pm2 start --only serverName --env production` has the online status but not working and no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that the pm2 process was not really killed. I had to delete the project and clone again from the repository. Then it works (I tried before a `git pull`, but git tells me that it was the latest version)